# Formatting nlargest output pandas

Tags: python, pandas, formatting

I'm new to pandas and so am a bit unfamiliar with how it works. I have processed some data and obtained the results I want, however, I am having trouble figuring out how to format the output with print. For instance, I only want to display certain rows of data, as well as putting certain values in ().

From doing this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data_file.csv')

tallmen = df[df['gender'] == 'M'].nlargest(2, 'height')
```

This is the output I get by doing print(tallmen):

```
    id    name            gender  state       height
6   5        Smith, Bob   M       New York    73.5
2   7     Wright, Frank   M       Kentucky    75.2
```

And this is the output I want:

```
Smith, Bob (M)  6' 1.5"
Wright, Frank (M)  6' 3.2"
```

When I tried to use tallmen as a dictionary, and that gave me an error. So I'm not quite sure what to do. Additionally, it there a way for me to be able to manipulate the height values so that I can reformat them (aka display them in the ft in format as shown below)?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new column this way:

```
In [207]: df
Out[207]:
   id           name gender     state  height
6   5     Smith, Bob      M  New York    73.5
2   7  Wright, Frank      M  Kentucky    75.2

In [208]: df['new'] = (
     ...:     df.name + ' (' + df.gender + ') ' +
     ...:     (df.height // 12).astype(int).astype(str) +
     ...:         "' " + (df.height % 12).astype(str) + '"')
     ...:

In [209]: df
Out[209]:
   id           name gender     state  height                        new
6   5     Smith, Bob      M  New York    73.5     Smith, Bob (M) 6' 1.5"
2   7  Wright, Frank      M  Kentucky    75.2  Wright, Frank (M) 6' 3.2"
```

Comment: more importantly, I need to figure out how to only print certain columns rather than the whole dataframe - how would I do that

Comment: @mildlyillogical, can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

My professor helped me figure this out. Really what I needed was to know how to iterate through values in the DataFrame. My solution looks like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data_file.csv')

tallmen = df[df['gender'] == 'M'].nlargest(2, 'height')    

for i, val in tallmen.iterrows():
    feet = val['height']//12
    inches = val['height']%12

    print("%s (%s) %i'%i"" % (val['name'], val['gender'],
                                     feet, inches))
```